# Is it possible to orderby random for Grid fieldtype?

Tags: grid

As far as I can tell, orderby="random" does not work on the new Grid fieldtype. Has anyone found a good workaround?

I have a grid with several images. I'd like to display one at a time, but randomize which image shows.

Answer (score 5):

As of EE 2.7.3 this is possible via the native orderby="random" parameter.
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/grid.html#orderby

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Grid has that option, but you can use our little Shoe Shine Toolbox plugin to generate a random number. [Get it from Github](https://github.com/shoeshine/shoeshine-toolbox).

With it, you can do this:

```
{grid-field row_id="{exp:shoeshine_toolbox:random_number from='1' to='10'}"}
  ...
{/grid-field}
```

Note: There are other great add-ons that can generate random numbers. Just do a search on www.devot-ee.com

Comment: I did try this approach with the "Low Random" plugin, but get php errors and no output for the field. I believe parse order is causing some grief between the Grid parameters and the Low Random plugin.